# I'm using python to remove the repeated character in a string, is there any way to do this except 'not in' and set()?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a function to do this, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Did I miss anything? I try to avoid using 'not in' and set() and anything that C++ doesn't have. But the output is either the same as the input or just no puput at all

```
def find(number):
global key
for m in range(len(match)):
    if number == match[m]:
        key = match[m]
        break
    else:
        key = None

def find1(number1):
    if number1 == None:
        return True
    else:
        return False

a = str(input())
match = '0'

for i in range(len(a)):
    b = find(a[i])
    if find1(b):
        match += a[i]
    
print(match)
```

Comment: " I try to avoid using 'not in' and set() and anything that C++ doesn't have" why on earth would you do that?

Comment: `def find1` seems incredibly pointless. just use `is None`. And in general, `if <condition> return True else return False` should just be `return <condition>`

Comment: Anyway, `def find1` *always* returns `None`, which seems to be your problem. You seem to assume that it does, but it doesn't, but you wrote it to mutate the global variable `key`. and there are no `return` statements, so by default it alway returns `None`. Relying on mutable global state is a very bad practice anyway, so you probably should just return someting

Comment: Aha, it's a funny exercise tho. The main reason that I want to do this is that I 'm new to Python, and wonder how 'not in' can be achieved. The reason that I didn't use return is that I want to iterate for all elements in match, but return will terminate this process early

Comment: I removed def find1 and make a small change for def find, it works now. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this in Python in a manner that avoids "anything that C++ doesn't have", however it seemed an interesting exercise so comparable solutions in both Python and C++ below.

The solution(s) below use regular expressions (built-in [`re` library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and standard library [`regex` header for C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex)). Each example matches any single character as the first capture group using `(.)` and then uses `\1+` to identify one or more repetitions of the first character matched, if this pattern matches (i.e. there is a repeated character), this operation is performed left-to-right over the entire string and the string following this operation is returned - i.e. a copy of the original string with repeated characters pruned.

**Python Solution**

```py
def remove_repeated(s):
    return re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', s)

s = input("Enter a string: ")

print(remove_repeated(s))
```

**C++ Solution**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;  

string remove_repeated(string s)
{
    regex r ("(.)\\1+");
    return s = regex_replace(s, r, "$1");    
}

int main ()
{
    string s;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> s;
    s = remove_repeated(s);
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
tteessttiinngg
```

**Output:**

```
testing
```

Input and output the same over both Python and C++ solutions when testing.